# Position of Reish Galusa

Tags: history, malchut-royalty, golus-exile

Does anyone know why the position of Reish Galusa no longer exists and when it was discontinued?

Comment: Simple: you tell me who should be it and if we all think it's reasonable we will reinstate him. Good luck finding such a person.

Comment: You dont think any of the Gedolim would be suitable or just that we would never be able to get everyone to agree? I think its pretty universally accepted in the Chareidi world that Rav Shteinman Shlita is currently the Gadol Hador. Although I think the Reish Galusa needed to be from the line of Dovid Hamelech, not sure though.

Comment: The latter. Moreover I personally was not aware that Rav Shteinman is now considered to be such, so I wonder how universal acceptance of him would be.

Answer (score 7):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exilarch

> The last exilarch (Reish Galusa) whose name is recorded is Hezekiah.
>   He was imprisoned and tortured to death in 1040. He was the last
>   exilarch.

However [daat.ac.il](http://www.daat.ac.il/encyclopedia/value.asp?id1=1493) says that it ended earlier by the leaders of the Jews due to fears of the Muslims.

> בשנת 941 מת נשיא הגולה דוד בן זכאי, ורב סעדיה גאון, איש ריבו לפנים,‏
>   התעלם מן הריב שביניהם, והחליט להושיב את בנו יהודה על כסא הנשיאות. ,‏
>   הוא כיהן שבעה חדשים ומת. במותו הניח בן קטן בגיל 12 שנה. רב סעדיה אסף‏
>   את הנער לביתו, חנכהו והכשירו למשרה שנועדה לו. הוא היה הנשיא האחרון. לא‏
>   ידוע דבר עליו, וגם שמו נעלם מאתנו. הוא נרצח בידי המוסלמים הקנאים שקנאו‏
>   במעמדו ובזכרון בית דוד. מפחד קנאי המוסלמים הסכימו ראשי כנסת ישראל בבבל‏
>   שלא למנות ראש גולה חדש ולבטל את נשיאות הגולה כליל.‏

To translate:

> In the year 941 the exilarch David ben Zakai died,
>   and Rav Saadia Gaon, who had previously quarreled him,
>   ignored the feud and determined to seat [David ben Zakai’s] son Yehudah
>   on the *nasi*’s throne.
>   He served seven months then died, leaving behind a minor son twelve years of age.
>   Rav Saadia brought the boy into his house and raised him,
>   preparing him for the rôle of leadership intended for him.
>   He was the last *nasi* [= exilarch].
>   Nothing is known of him; even his name has been lost to us.
>   He was murdered by Muslim fundamentalists
>   who were jealous of his standing and of the memory of [*malchut*] *beit David*.
>   For fear of Muslim fundamentalists,
>   the community leaders in Bavel agreed to not appoint a new exilarch
>   and to abolish the office entirely.

Comment: Very interesting! It is curious that we would not re institute the position after these fears dissipated.